# Customize dialog shape like padlock

Tags: qt, dialog, standards, shapes

I want to ask, how i can change the standard rectangular form of QDialog.I have got padlock as background image, but how i can make the dialog to accept this form, like on some online games starting menu.
Example image - > http://postimg.org/image/6tjxr8jqj/

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of this for QT called Shaped Clock Example.

You can search for it or try this [link](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/widgets-shapedclock.html) for the 4.7 version.

Comment: Thanks for the help dunc123. With your help i found other information, that i really needed.